# Get a screen shot of UICollectionView only?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am taking a screen shot of the whole screen, but i would like to take a screen shot of only the content of the collection view, this is because there is a menu view above it, and i would like to get only the content in the collection , right now i am using this to capture the screen = collection + menu :

```
 UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                       CGRect trect = rect;
                       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(trect.size);
                       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                       [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
                       UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code capture a yourCollectionView

```
CGRect rect = [yourCollectionView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[yourCollectionView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This saves the UIImage in jpg format with 95% quality in the app's document folder if you need to do that.

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/capturedImage.jpg"]];    
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 0.95) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Hope this would help you...